# Checking if JSON has updated with new data

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension to use with teachers in a school district which displays important announcements in a popup window. **[I'm using a published Google Spreadsheet to create a JSON feed](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/10j8Ycax02XMkVWMK1v-aYJMHoOjQaLRFuZUOKZEY9nA/od6/public/values?alt=json)** parsed by jQuery in the background script.

I'd like to add a badge to the extension icon when the data in the spreadsheet is changed, but I have no idea how to check if the JSON has been updated. The JSON from Google has a date hash (`data.feed.updated.$t`) and I think that's the way to go, but I can't tell what formatting it's using.

**How should I write the conditional `if` in my `windowPopup.js` script to check if the data has been updated?**

## windowPopup.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth()+1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var output = (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + d.getFullYear();
  $('#date').append('<h1>'+output+'</h1>');

  var spreadsheetId = "10j8Ycax02XMkVWMK1v-aYJMHoOjQaLRFuZUOKZEY9nA";

  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetId + "/od6/public/values?alt=json";

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var entry = data.feed.entry;

    $(entry).each(function() {
      $('.data').append('<h2>'+this.gsx$title.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$text.$t+'</p>');
    });

    console.log(data.feed.updated.$t);
    console.log(d);

    // I'm not sure how to check if the data has been updated
    // Currently, these will never match, so it's always badged.

    if(d != data.feed.updated.$t) {
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: "!"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a pretty awesome library to do json comparisons: https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `localStorage` to save the `updated` timestamp from the JSON response.  Chrome extensions can repeatedly call a function using `chrome.alarms.create`, so you could check on an interval (say, once a minute) to evaluate whether your JSON timestamp is not the same as the one in `localStorage`.

The conditional in your script could then check to see whether a `localStorage` key exists.  If it *does not* exist, create it and set it to the timestamp from the JSON response.  It was the first time the script executed, and it'll be available the next time the `alarm` you create fires.

If it *does* exist, your script could compare the locally-stored value with the `updated` timestamp on subsequent JSON requests.  If the two match, there hasn't been an update.  If they differ, there has been an update and you can display a badge / take whatever other actions you'd like.

Here's an example of one way to accomplish this:

```
function isUpdated(jsonTimestamp) {
  var storedTimestamp = localStorage.getItem("last-updated");
  if (storedTimestamp === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("last-updated", jsonTimestamp);
    return false;
  }

  if (storedTimestamp === jsonTimestamp) {
    return false;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("last-updated", jsonTimestamp);
    return true;
  }
}

function checkJsonFeed() {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var entry = data.feed.entry;

    $(entry).each(function() {
      $('.data').append('<h2>'+this.gsx$title.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$text.$t+'</p>');
    });

    if (isUpdated(data.feed.updated.$t)) {
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: "!"
      });
    }
}

checkJsonFeed();
chrome.alarms.create(
  "checkJsonFeed", 
  {
    delayInMinutes: 1,
    periodInMinutes: 1
  }
);

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  checkJsonFeed();
});
```

More information on `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

More information on `alarms` in the Google Chrome extension API:  https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms